# eclipse cannot resolve R.id/layout

Tags: java, android, eclipse

In my eclipse the values R.id.[something] and R.layout.[something] can not be resolved but the files/ids exist!

I already cleaned the project multiple times, and also tried to rename the files/ids...

**SOLVED:**
Deleted the

```
import android.R
```

and then it worked

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**

Delete you R.java file and clean once, if doesn't work make sure that your project don't have any errors. Check in problems if any exists

---

Just clean your project once.

```
 Project-->clean..>select your prject.
```

Comment: I deleted R.java (after I delete it, it immediately appears again in the gen folder!?) then I did a clean again but still got the errors

Comment: @user1606657 gen folder and R.java in it will be automatically generated after the clean, because it builds again. So delete your gen folder and clean your project once

Answer (score 2):

Try doing a clean in Eclipse.  If that doesn't work, make sure that the gen folder of your project is included in the Java Build Path of the Eclipse project, and is above the src folder in the ordering of paths.

Comment: the gen folder is included and above the src folder

Comment: @user1606657 you can delete gen folder also, it will automatically generate, when you clean your project

Answer (score 0):

1. Clean the project.
2. Make sure there are no any errors that would not allow project to be build.
3. Force project build.